# PHP not accepting single quotes?

Tags: php

All of a sudden, code that has worked for weeks will throw a syntax error on single quotes.

For example

```
$dueshtml .= '>'. $value .'</option>' . "\n";
```

now throws a parse error, and it executed perfectly before. 
Changing the single quotes to double quotes and escaping any double quotes in literal text allows the line to pass, but I have no burning desire to go though 675 lines of code to convert all of them.

The single quote is indeed ascii 39.

Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: What's the exact error message? Can you post the lines before and after this one line?

Comment: What is the message of the parse error?

Comment: Single quotes are fine.  Your error is on prior lines, or you have some junk data/unprintable characters in your file.

Comment: Agreed, there's nothing syntactically wrong with that line.  You'd need to supply more info for us to help you.

Comment: error is [quote]Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in <blahblah>.php on line 554[[/quote]

Comment: Probably a syntax error somewhere else in your code.  Read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447606/php-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string) for more info.

Comment: code is [code] if (isset($_POST["member_type"])  && $_POST["member_type"] == $key ) {
$dueshtml .= " selected=\"selected\"";
}
$dueshtml .= '>'.$value.'</option>' . "\n";  
}[/code]

echo $dueshtml;

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Found the problem 42 lines of html code before the line that triggered the parse error.